# Importing large datasets into Couchbase

Tags: couchbase

I am having difficulty importing large datasets into Couchbase.  I have experience doing this very fast with Redis via the command line but I have not seen anything yet for Couchbase.

I have tried using the PHP SDK and it imports about 500 documents / second.  I have also tried the cbcdocload script in the Couchbase bin folder but it seems to want each document in its on JSON file. It is a bit of work to create all these files and then load them.  Is there some other importation process I am missing?  If cbcdocload is the only way load data fast then is it possible to put multiple documents into 1 json file.

Answer (score 1):

Take the file that has all the JSON documents in it and zip up the file:

```
zip somefile.zip somefile.json
```

Place the zip file(s) into a directory. I used ~/json_files/ in my home directory.

Then load the file or files by the following command:

```
cbdocloader -u Administrator -p s3kre7Pa55 -b MyBucketToLoad -n 127.0.0.1:8091 -s 1000 \
~/json_files/somefile.zip
```

Note: '-s 1000' is the memory size. You'll need to adjust this value for your bucket.

If successful you'll see output stating how many documents were loaded, success, etc.

Here is a brief script to load up a lot of .zip files in a given directory:

```
#!/bin/bash
JSON_Dir=~/json_files/
for ZipFile in $JSON_Dir/*.zip ; 
do /Applications/Couchbase\ Server.app/Contents/Resources/couchbase-core/bin/cbdocloader  \
    -u Administrator -p s3kre7Pa55 -b MyBucketToLoad                                  \
    -n 127.0.0.1:8091 -s 1000 $ZipFile
 done
```

**UPDATED:** Keep in mind this script will only work if your data is formatted correctly or if the files are less than the max single document size of 20MB. (not the zipfile, but any document extracted from the zip)

I have created a blog post describing bulk loading from a single file as well and it is listed here:

[Bulk Loading Documents Into Couchbase](http://couchbaseallday.blogspot.com/2014/11/bulk-loading-documents-in-couchbase.html?view=classic)

Comment: I have tried that but a single file was not working. I will try again.  The one piece is that cbcdocloader uses the filename as the key.  Is that what your setup is doing?  I need like 25 million+ keys

Comment: the syntax I pasted and the procedure I used, on Mac and Ubuntu, came directly from a session where I imported several million keys. (only 4M in my case). The only modification to the procedure was the file names, etc. Be sure that you are using compressed files. There *could* be a document number limit per file but I'm not aware of one. Do you have the syntax and setup similar to what I described above?

Comment: I would like to point out one other thing. Cbdocloader uses filenames as the doc_id. My script does not. You can provide a constant key or it will pull out a specified attribute from the json document and use that as the key + a hash value of the doc.